# Include hyperlink <a> in jQuery .Content

Tags: jquery

I'm playing along with this snippet in order to remove breakpoints (`<br/>`) and wrap my text in paragraphs:

```
$('.articleText').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3;
}).wrap('<p></p>').end().filter('br').remove();
```

source: http://api.jquery.com/contents/

The problem is that my text contains a hyperlink () which is not being included in the paragraph - it's simply being left out side...

This is my textsnippet:

`Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. <br/><br/>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a <a href="#">galley</a> of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.`

this is how it's transformed:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a</p> 
<a href="#">galley</a> 
<p>of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
```

and this is how it should be:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a <a href="#">galley</a> of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
```

How is this possible...?

Answer (score 0):

The method `.contents()` only returns the contents of the *children* of the caller, not all of the descendants. Because your `<a>` tag is nested within a child, it will not be picked up by the `.contents()` method.

Try this:

```
$('.articleText').contents().add($(this).find("*").contents())...
```

Note: I have not yet tested the above, so it may need some minor tweaks.

**UPDATE:** If I am misunderstanding you and the `<a>` tag is not supposed to be embedded, then you have an error in your markup:

Try changing:

`<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<p>`

to

`<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>`

Let me know if you have any questions on this. Good luck! :)

Comment: No luck yet - there was an error in my markup which is now corrected... - my question is basically: "how do I wrap both plain text AND links in the same paragraph...?" - so far my link stands outside the paragraph...